# Change error message for ASP.NET custom validator using javascript (client-side validation)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to change the error message for ASP.NET custom validator using javascript (client-side validation)?

I know that we can easily change it using server side function i.e

```
customvalidtor1..ErrorMessage = "Error"
```

This will change error message for CustomValidator. How can we do same using client-side function? I have tried hard but did not find any answer.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have tried and it works fine for me.here is a simple solution for this problem

```
$(source).text("* Not a NA Phone #");
```